# jQuery use .slice().each to start the loop on a different index

Tags: jquery, each, slice

I am in need of reading an incremented XML file.
So using a recursive function I pass the value of the latest `index` to `.slice().each` but for some reasons when the function is called again it stops completely.
What's wrong?
Why it does not slice to the next specified index?
What's wrong in my code?

```
function processXML(indexValue) {
    var tocURL = "../broadcasted.xml";
    $.get(tocURL, function(d) {
        var length = $(d).find('tweet').length;
        var count = indexValue;
        $(d).find('tweet').slice(count).each(function(index) {

            var cvdIndexId = $(this).find("index");
            var cvdTweetAuthor = $(this).find("author").text();
            var cvdTweetDescription = $(this).find("description").text();
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (index == (length - 1)) {
                    processXML(index + 1);
                    //alert(index+1);
                } else if (cvdTweetAuthor === "Animator") {
                    $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
                    obj = $('#cvd_bubble_left').append(makeCvdBubbleAnimator(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                    obj.fitText(7.4);
                    $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
                } else {
                    $('#cvd_bubble_right').html('');
                    obj = $('#cvd_bubble_right').append(makeCvdBubble(cvdIndexId, cvdTweetAuthor, cvdTweetDescription));
                    obj.fitText(7.4);
                    $('#cvd_bubble_left').html('');
                }
            }, index * 1000);
        });
    });
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root bubbles="7">
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <author><![CDATA[@Liciiious]]></author>
        <description><![CDATA[#EveryoneLovesBeinsport (cc @beinsport @charlesbietry). #pureLIVE]]></description>
        <index>1</index>
    </tweet>
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Message]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[beIN Sport]]></author>
        <index>2</index>
    </tweet>
        <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <author><![CDATA[@Liciiious2]]></author>
        <description><![CDATA[#EveryoneLovesBeinsport (cc @beinsport @charlesbietry). #pureLIVE]]></description>
        <index>3</index>
    </tweet>
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Message]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[Animator]]></author>
        <index>4</index>
    </tweet>
        <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <author><![CDATA[@MAuricious]]></author>
        <description><![CDATA[#EveryoneLovesBeinsport (cc @beinsport @charlesbietry). #pureLIVE]]></description>
        <index>5</index>
    </tweet>
    <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Message]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[beIN Sport]]></author>
        <index>6</index>
    </tweet>
        <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Messagexxx]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[beIN Sportxxx]]></author>
        <index>7</index>
    </tweet>
        <tweet broadcasted="bubble">
        <description><![CDATA[Messagexxxzzzz]]></description>
        <author><![CDATA[beIN Sportxxxzzzz]]></author>
        <index>8</index>
    </tweet>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you slice an array, you create a new array. This is causing a mismatch between what 'index' is meant to be and what it actuall is inside your each() function. For example, when index == 0 it isn't the first tweet in the whole DOM, it is the first tweet from your sliced array.

I think the solution is to set 'length' to the length of the sliced array, rather than the original array. Something along the lines of:

```
var count = indexValue;    
var new_tweets = $(d).find('tweet').slice(count);
var length = new_tweets.length;

new_tweets.each(function(index) {
```

You will also need to change the argument you pass into processXML from within your timeout.

```
if (index == (length - 1)) {
    processXML(count + length);
    //alert(index+1);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show a sample? If it works I'll accept your answer. This is driving me crazy :D